# How to use ASCII code for Enter in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am having a little problem getting my code to do what I want.

I want to prevent the user from using the Enter button when he/she is entering text into a text. The code I am using is:

```
 Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress
    If Asc(e.KeyChar) = 13 Then
        e.Handled = False
    Else
        e.Handled = True
        MsgBox("Error.")
    End If
End Sub
```

This not achieving my objective. Please how can I re-write this?

Comment: Do you have any reason not to use the AcceptsReturn Property of the textbox?

Comment: It seems you are blocking everything except enter.

Comment: @Tim3880 - Quite right. Thanks to your observation and PaulAds' below; I see my error and have gotten it working now.

Comment: @user1937198 - Thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately, I had tried that but it did not work for me :( But PaulAd (below) has gotten me sorted. But thanks for taking the time to respond to me. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with Tim3880. You are indeed keeping the user from entering anything with his/her keyboard; except the enter value. Your code is okay; only wrongly arranged, friend.

Try this:

```
 Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress
    If Asc(e.KeyChar) = 13 Then
        e.Handled = True
        MsgBox("Error.")
    Else
        e.Handled = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! That had me sorted.